# res.render sends data back in String format

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post

I am developing an app with the node, express, and mongoose. In my login module, `res.render()` the function sends the code back to the client side ajax call as string format data. Whereas I wanted it to render a particular view. ajax call is post type call. I can see the entire HTML in string format in success field of ajax.

I did search for similar problem and solutions, but I couldn't find any. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

#### Client Side :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/login',
    data: userDetail,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(err){
      $("p").text("Invalid User Details")
    }
  });
```

#### Server Side :

```
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser ,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    User.find({name : req.body.name , password : req.body.pass},function(err,data){
        if (data.length != 0){
            Todo.find({},function(err,todo){
                if (err) throw err;
                var token = jwt.sign(req.body,config.secret,{
                    expiresIn : '1h'
                }); 
                res.render('todo',{
                    todos : todo,
                    token : token
                });
            });
        }
        else 
            res.status(401).json({ msg : "Invalid User" });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't get what is your problem? What do you want?

Comment: I want it to be render the page. not send it to the client.

Comment: Then do, `$('div').html(data);` in your ajax success callback; it wont just magically appear in your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax calls do not, by themselves, change what is displayed in the browser.  They just fetch data and your Javascript code them decides what to do with that data.  This is true no matter what type of Ajax call it is, GET, POST, etc...

If you want to change the current page to show the content you fetched with Ajax, then you have to insert that content into the current page yourself.

Or, in the case of a POST, perhaps you want to submit an HTML form and then the browser will render the content that comes back from that form post for you, but an ajax post will not change what the browser displays at all.

Submitting an HTML form can be done either via Javascript or via native user actions (without any Javascript).  But, for the browser to process the result for you, it has to be the browser submitting the form, not an ajax call sending the form.  If an Ajax call sends the form (as in the code you show), then the result just comes back to your Javascript and it's up to your Javascript to decide what to do with that result (insert it in the page, etc...).